# Unexpected optimization happens when declaring object and calling function with it in the same line

Tags: c++

I know it is not the best practice writing code like this, but it just happened.

It is basically about a function like

```cpp
C &foo(C &c); // will assign value to c and return c
```

and a line initializing an object by a self-assignment through the function, like

```cpp
C c = foo(c);
```

Here is my simplified code:

```cpp
class C {
        public:
        C(int i): _i(i) {}
        C(const C& c): _i(c._i){}
        int _i;
};



C &foo(C &c) {
        c = 10;
        return c;
}



int main() {
        C c = foo(c);
        cout << c._i << endl;
        return 0;
}
```

The function yields different result if compiled with -O3.  Without optimization, the result is 10 as expected.  With -O3, the result becomes 0.  I know gcc must optimize away something, most likely about the constructor of C, but I cannot figure it out.

If C is replaced with a primitive type, e.g. int, then the function yields the same result between optimized and non-optimized code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember that the "assignment" in the definition is really copy-construction. With

```
C c = foo(c);
```

what you do is equivalent to

```
C c(foo(c));
```

And the problem here is that when `foo(c)` is called, the object `c` haven't been constructed yet, leading to *undefined behavior!*

Answer (score 2):

This has nothing to do with optimisation; your program's behaviour is not well-defined. When you change some compiler settings you observe the consequences of that.

When you pass a reference to `c` into `foo`, it has not yet been initialised. You are allowed to use it but only in limited ways. Here you assign a result to it. Then you return the reference again. *Then it is copy-initialised from itself.* Clearly an initialisation cannot happen *after* an assignment.

Rework your approach.

Why not make it simple?

```
C c;
foo(c);
```

Comment: Sure! Just curious about the reason behind the bug.